# Tried everything -- Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, dalvik, abort

From what I read, this error could be caused by duplicate references to classes existing in diff jar files and that seemed to be the case after I fiddled with the Build Path. BUT, all I have was the android.jar and the android-support-v4.jar on my Build path and under the Referenced libraries which I need to get a clean build.

I cleaned the project, deleted the R.java, closed and reopened the project but am still getting this right off the bet. What else can I do to fix this? I need both .jar files and they are the only ones included in my project.

Console Log:

```
[2012-01-29 13:05:30 - HelloFragmentLayout] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/security/auth/callback/PasswordCallback.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-01-29 13:05:30 - HelloFragmentLayout] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-01-29 13:05:30 - HelloFragmentLayout] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to run an example app written for android 3 under android 4. I commented-out the body of every method in every class and tried to remove the android.jar from the classpath and I don't get the error message anymore. And it works even when I comment-in the code previously out-commented... strange :( Unfortunately I'm not sure if this is the proper solution since I get a NPE while trying to run the app in question. What about you?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same problem, and I realized that I have added Android library twice, also the JRE environment. Just make sure that Java build path of the project only contains one Android platform as the library, and not JRE. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any other library or jar files that you might be using apart from the android library. Chances are you might be using the Android library and also have added the jar for android from "Add Jar" option. If so, remove the additional jar. After that, a clean build should solve your problem.